# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).aaDropdownMenu is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation, turbolinks

I am working on a Ruby on Rails 4.2 application and using foundation 6

Sometimes as I am navigating through the app I get a turbolink error and the header breaks throwing this error which gets resolved refreshing the page, but I want to remove this bug.

[image]

**application.js**

```
$(function(){ 
    $(document).foundation(); 
});

$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() { 
    $(document).foundation();
});
```

**Note:** This error happens when I click a link, but it happens sometimes, it seems to happen mostly when I haven't visited the page in a while.

Comment: `aaDropdownMenu` is nothing which we define in Foundation Sites. How was this defined in your project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389566/error-in-console-browser-uncaught-typeerror-aadropdownmenu-is-not-a-f

Comment: I got this error when upgrading to Rails 7 and trying to use importmaps with ActiveAdmin (in addition to Sprockets for JS). My `application.js` file was loading `foundation-sites` and it seemed to be causing a conflict with the `aaDropdownMenu` in the ActiveAdmin code. https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/app/javascript/active_admin/initializers/dropdown-menu.js  I couldn't figure out how to get around the conflict though, and dropped the idea of using importmaps.